# Filtering a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of identical dictionaries

```
list_dict = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]
```

Now I want to filter a particular dictionary with value of id say id = 2

I do

```
list_filtered = [ dict for dict in list_dict if dict['id'] == 2]
```

Above solution works but what if I have a very long list it will inefficient to iterate over the whole list and check if id matches. Any other workarounds?

Comment: you should use numpy array

Comment: A different data structure? Why a list of dictionaries and not a dictionary of dictionaries, keyed on the id (or a dictionary of lists of dictionaries if ids aren't unique)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a generator expression and get one match at a time, like this

```
matcher = (d for d in list_dict if d['id'] == 2)
print next(matcher, None)
```

When you call `next` on the same generator object, it will resume the loop from where it left, the last time.

```
print next(matcher, None)
```

The second argument to `next` is the default value to return if the generator expression is exhausted.

Comment: you didn't understands the question properly. This solution is inefficient if having list contains large number of dictionaries

Comment: @user3214779 as the question written that's a very good answer, you asked about a very long list and generators are a good approach for large or infinite lists, in all other cases (speed bound) list comprehensions will do the trick. to understand you can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/47789/1982962)

Comment: @KobiK look at the no. of times the for loop will iterate over the list which will take a lot of time.

Comment: @user3214779 you have to "iterate" if you want to check for matches, the difference is whether you want the list to be saved in the memory while running, if it's a very long list that's not a good approach. if you want to save iteration time you can put it in to the list sorted then you can save a lot of time in the match find.

Comment: Hmm, I am talking about long list as written in the question.

Comment: @user3214779 It will not iterate over the entire list multiple times, but it will stop iterating once it finds a match.

Comment: no no. you aren't considering the case when the element is supposed to be last. :)

Comment: @user3214779 Change of DS would be the best way I guess, unless the data is sorted...

Answer (score 0):

Python provides a functional filter:

```
filter(lambda x: x["id"]==2,list_dict)
```

You can also us the iterator provided by `itertools` package:

```
itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x["id"] ==2, list_dict)
```

`ifilter` will apply the function passed element by element.

If you want the iteration the stop at the first match you can try something like:

```
itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x["id"] !=2, list_dict).next()
```